# Compare File Versions (low or high) command(.cmd)

Tags: batch

I extracted the "chrome.exe" version with the command below. I want to get the value compared to the extracted version.

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

FOR /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%I IN (
  'wmic datafile where "name='C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe'" get version /format:list'
) DO FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ("%%I") DO SET "ChromeVersion=%%A"

if version=94.0.4606.71
```

I want
Exit if higher than the version value.
`if %ChromeVersion%==higher goto end`

Install if lower than the version value.
`if %ChromeVersion%==lower goto install`

Comment: Please see [how to ask a good question](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask). Please update your question with 1) the script you currently use 2) the expected result and output 3) the actual result and output. [From Review](https://superuser.com/help/reviews-intro)

Comment: https://www.online-tech-tips.com/software-reviews/how-to-automatically-update-free-software-with-chocolatey/

Comment: Is the version correctly saved in %ChromeVersion%?

Comment: version correctly saved in %ChromeVersion% OK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```bath
@echo off 

for /f usebackq^tokens^=3 %%i in (
  `reg query HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Google\Chrome\BLBeacon /v version`
   )do set "_current=%%~i"
 
 set "_version=94.0.4606.71"
 set "_current=%_current:.=%0000000"

 if %_current:~0,9% lss %_version:.=% (
      goto :install )else goto :eOf
```

---

You don't need to use a double `for` to do this, hence no need to use `setlocal enableDelayedExpansion`

---

## Some further reading:

- **[`Set /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)**
- **[Where does `GOTO :EOF` return to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37515901/where-does-goto-eof-return-to)**
- **[`If condition() else condition()`](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)**
- **[`Goto :Label /?` | or | `Call :Label /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/goto.html)**
- **[`Set variable=variable:substrings` | DOS - String Manipulation](https://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php)**
- **[`Reg Query` | Windows Registry location for Google Chrome version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45642175/8177207)**

Comment: Is the comparison `lss` a string or value comparison?  I am wondering if it still work when Chrome version goes beyond 100 in the short future.
(p.s. interesting question and answer - I didn't do further testing)

Comment: Here's a few of my test results:
`C:\>if "1234" lss "94" (echo smaller) else echo bigger`
smaller

`C:\>if 1234 lss 94 (echo smaller) else echo bigger`
bigger

`C:\>if 1234.123.123 lss 94.0.4606.71 (echo smaller) else echo bigger`
smaller

`C:\>if 1234.123 lss 94.0.4606.71 (echo smaller) else echo bigger`
smaller

Comment: @KennethL The `if` comparison of integers takes place without/removing the dot from variables...  
your `if` test does not `".o.c.c.u.r."` as the answer `if` code `occurs`, also without `""`, number don't need **[`""`](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)** d:)

Comment: Ah ha! I missed out the part about DOS string manipulation, which removed all dots `.`.  The next question pop up in my mind was, what if previous minor version number contained more digits, or future minor version number contains less digit? (like 91.0.12345.102)?  Luckily my naked eye did not see such occurrence.  So your answer should work.

Comment: @KennethL [really well observed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome_version_history)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help. I have implemented the action I want.

```
set ChromeDeploryVersion=94.0.4606.71

for /f usebackq^tokens^=3 %%i in (
  `reg query HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Google\Chrome\BLBeacon /v version`
   )do set "_current=%%~i"
echo.
echo The current version of Chrome is %_current%
echo.
 set "_version=%ChromeDeploryVersion%"
 
  if %_current%==%ChromeDeploryVersion% goto VersionSame
 
 set "_current=%_current:.=%0000000"
 
 if %_current:~0,9% lss %_version:.=% (
      goto :install) else (goto :HighVersion
      )

:VersionSame
echo.
echo.
echo ▶ Chrome version is same.
echo.
echo.
goto end

:install 
echo.
echo.
echo ▶ Chrome version is low.
echo.
echo.
goto end

:HighVersion
echo.
echo.
echo ▶ Chrome version is high.
echo.
echo.
goto end
```

Comment: **[Your `goto end` means  (intent) `goto :eof`  End Of File?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37515901/where-does-goto-eof-return-to)**

Comment: We will implement it so that it operates by dividing it into three options: setting options/installing/exiting.